# Optimizing Telerik ASP.NET AJAX Controls

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, telerik-ajax

Any good sources(links) about optimizing Telerik Web controls? I imagine that there are features that are turned on by default. These features require resources (javascript, css, images) to be downloaded on request. It would be nice to know what these feature are and to turn them off if not used.

Do you know of such features? I'm primarily interested in Telerik AJAX components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

[Optimizing output, page load time and the overall performance of RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/optimizing_output_and_page_load_time_by_using_radscriptmanager_and_radstylesheetmanager.html)

[RadInput vs. RadInputManager](http://www.telerikwatch.com/2009/02/optimization-tips-radinput-vs.html)

[Using RadAjaxManagerProxy Controls](http://telerikwatch.com/2008/05/optimization-tips-using.html)

Did you even try searching anything?

Comment: I tried searching Telerik's knowledge base. It would be great if all the answers to optimizing their controls could be aggregated into this post. Its best for everyone.

Comment: Ty - I assure you performance is not an after thought. We work hard to enable devs to have full control over the RadControls, and we're always striving to maximize performance. That said, you should only use rich UI controls when you need them to achieve best performance, so be cautious of replacing all default controls with rich controls as a rule of thumb. If you've hit a specific perf problem, let me know and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I also found these sources on the Telerik site recently when looking for performance boost techniques:

[Top performance page](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/resources/top-performance.aspx)

[Support Center RadControls Performance section](http://www.telerik.com/support/aspnet-ajax.aspx)

They look pretty descriptive and cover most of their controls.

Dick

Answer (score 0):

Here is more:

[Optimizing output, page load time and overall performance](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/optimizing_output_and_page_load_time_by_using_radscriptmanager_and_radstylesheetmanager.html)

[Top 15 optimization tips and tricks in public forums](http://blogs.telerik.com/ToddAnglin/Posts/07-05-14/Top_15_Optimization_Tips_and_Tricks.aspx?ReturnURL=/ToddAnglin/Posts.aspx%3fPage%3d3)