# How to speed up Telerik Ajax performance?

Tags: telerik

I have used the telerik control in my site, when I load the page, the page loaded very slow. I check it but at runtime many `webresource.axd` file is made and `scriptresource.axd` file is made, so how to run fast telerik control and increase the site performance.

Comment: Can you mark the correct answer please?

Answer (score 2):

Telerik has a page on their site about how to boost their AJAX controls performance:

[How the Telerik ASP.NET AJAX Controls Help You Build Better-Performing Apps Faster](http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tech-sheets/top-performance)

Comment: This explains why using telerik you can achieve better performances, not how to boost performance on existing telerik-using applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional links on RadGrid and RadControls performance optimizations:

[RadGrid client/server performance optimizations](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdviewstatereductiontechniques.html)

[RadAjax client-side performance optimizations](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxclientsideperformance.html)

[Optimizing RadGrid ViewState usage](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdviewstateoptimization.html)

[Saving the grid ViewState in Session](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdsavinggridviewstateinsession.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to boost resource generation look at [this article on telerik support site](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-optimizing-output-page-load-time-using-radscriptmanager-radstylesheetmanager.html).

Also consider reading this answer: [Optimizing Telerik ASP.NET AJAX Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748860/optimizing-telerik-asp-net-ajax-controls/748894#748894)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Telerik reports then here is a [general article](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-performance.html) on boosting Telerik report performance.